# some questions on pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am wrinting a pipeline job,this is my code:

```
pipeline {

agent any
stages {
    stage('Example Build') {
        steps {
            sh '...'
        }
    }
    stage('Example Build2') {    
        steps {
            sh '...'
        }
    }
    parallel {
        stage('Example Build3') {    
            steps {
                sh '...'
            }
        }
        stage('Example Build4') {    
            steps {
                echo '...'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

But it cause a error below,what can I do to solve it?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define `parallel` only inside a stage and not above it, see [Parallel Stages](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/)

> You can now specify either steps or parallel for a stage

Examples:

> ```
> stage('run-parallel-branches') {
>  steps {
>   parallel(
>
> stages {
>    stage('Run Tests') {
>       parallel {
> ```